# can't build spring boot application using gradle and ipv6 network

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, ipv6, gradle-plugin

I am trying to build a spring boot application in a VM with ipv6 network using Gradle, I seccedded to download the wrapper using this command :

```
sh gradlew -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true clean bootWar -Pstage
```

But I got the following issue :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':buildSrc:runtimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0.
  Required by:
      project :buildSrc
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/3.0.0/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-3.0.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/3.0.0/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Network is unreachable
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/3.0.0/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-3.0.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/3.0.0/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Network is unreachable
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://ipv6.repo1.maven.org/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/3.0.0/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-3.0.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://ipv6.repo1.maven.org/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/3.0.0/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Network is unreachable
```

**PS:**

the `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` is able to be downloaded using the `wget` command

I tried also to set some flags in JAVA_OPT like `-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true` and `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` but nothing is changed